# Does tar work in depthfirst mode or breadthfirst mode

Tags: linux, tar

I am executing `tar -zcvf` on a directory which has 4 sub directories. These directories are filling up almost 1TB of space on my hard disk, and creating a tar is adding to space used since I am running it without `--remove-files` option.

Based on the output of the tar command (I am running it in verbose mode), it seems like tar archives a directory depth-first, that is, completes one sub-directory and then moves on to the next one and so on.

Does that mean I can delete the sub directory that has been already processed and tar has moved on to the next sub-directory?

Comment: Hi karan, I see you have used `-z` that means `gzip`. So, you need to search `gzip` compression underlying algorithm - **DEFLATE** . Some useful Links : 1. **[Dissecting the Gzip format](http://www.infinitepartitions.com/art001.html)** is very helpful for examining code. 2. [Some Notes on Gzip algorithm](http://www.gzip.org/algorithm.txt) and 3. [How Gzip Compression Works](https://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/raul-fraile-how-gzip-compression-works.html). That's a lot of time investment. No matter If you get exact answer, just write your findings. That will be helpful for others. Best of Luck :)

Comment: Hi @C0deDaedalus, thanks for the help! I will check the resources and post my findings.